# Replace text in a cell containing a string with another string

Tags: excel, excel-2010

In Excel, how can I replace text in a cell containing a particular string, with another string?

The original values look like this

```
802-2553
802-1753
802-5589
103-4569
103-54879
303-1542
303-6589
502-1236
```

What I'm trying to do is replace all cells with `802` as the first 3 characters with the Text `Vehicle Loans`, `103` with the text `Home Loans` and `303` with `Saving Accounts`, `502` with `Other Loans`

So the end result is

```
Vehicle Loans
Vehicle Loans
Vehicle Loans
Home Loans
Home Loans
Savings Accounts
Savings Accounts
Other Loans
```

I tried with the Substitute Function, but it seems that function won't work for something like this.

What other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try combining `IF` and `LEFT`:

```
=IF(LEFT(A1,3)="802","Vehicle loans", IF(LEFT(A1,3)="103","Home loans",IF(LEFT(A1,3)="303","Saving account",IF(LEFT(A1,3)="502","Other account","Unknown account"))))
```

Use in an adjoining cell and copy and paste values.

Answer (score 1):

I wquld use a formula and a lookup table.

Construct your `ReplacementTable`

Then, with your data starting in `A2`, try this formula:

```
=VLOOKUP(--LEFT(A2,FIND("-",A2)-1),ReplacementTable,2,FALSE)
```

> ReplacementTable  Refers To: =Sheet1!$E$2:$F$6

Since I entered the "prefix" as a number in the lookup table, I have to use a number to do the lookup -- hence the double unary <kbd>--</kbd> preceding the `LEFT` function in the formula.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Both the answers above are excellent.

Or you could just use search and replace.  It's quick and dirty.

1. Ctrl-H
2. Find what:  "802-"
   Put the hyphen in so that it doesn't find values within the cell.
3. Replace with: "Vehicle Loans"
4. Repeat for the other codes you want to replace: 103, 303, etc